# Where are the Arduino Function Unit Tests kept? I want to submit a fix for a faulty Arduino function

Tags: arduino-uno, testing, map

I have coded a fix for a major problem with the Arduino `map` function (in `Arduino.h` & `arduino/avr/cores/arduino/WMath.cpp`).

I submitted it as a comment to [map function causes huge errors when mapping to small intervals due to integer truncation #10382](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/issues/10382) but heard nothing so far.

I thought it might be handled quicker if I can submit it as a Pull Request with Unit Tests to A) expose how and why `map` is faulty and B) show how my solution fixes the problem.

Comment: You should be submitting requests about the API to the API repository, not the core repository: https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-API

Comment: I am not aware of any unit tests within the Arduino core. I suggest you commit the code change with no tests, add a small test sketch (mostly `Serial.println()`) within the “cover letter” of the pull request, and state the results you get with and without the patch applied.

Comment: @Majenko note that the API is fine. It's the code in the core that does not implement the API properly (assuming that arduino/avr/cores/arduino/WMath.cpp is in the core)